# How to start ArangoDB-GraphQL-Express?

Tags: express, arangodb, express-graphql, arangojs

I looked at the support from ArangoDB, and google search, but it did not help me much...I am fresh in these topic, (*but Polish proverb says that you should not be ashamed to ask questions*).

my situation is as follows, I have quite a very extensive database, which I created by GUI-HTTP-ArangoDB (by importing further crafted JSONs, as collections of Verexs & Edges) I would like to link this database and dynamically depending on the query, display the resutat, only hmm I do not know how to connect it. is like a tutorial on the arango page to Node, but there is nothing to write like where and what to create, just they only described the next command that do something .. ech ...

I am looking for examples, or a step-by-step guide/tutorial..

I am asking you for help / support..

how in it, to find himself..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are two options I would use to connect Arango to GraphQL:

1 Use the Foxx micro services that live within Arango to create a Rest API. Then you can use wrap the Rest api in GraphQL. Here is the tutorial for creating the Foxx micro services :

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/foxx-microservices/getting-started/
And here is the tutorial to wrap the the rest api in GraphQL:

https://www.prisma.io/blog/how-to-wrap-a-rest-api-with-graphql-8bf3fb17547d/

2 Have the GraphQL Server be part of the Foxx microservices instead of the Rest Api as described here
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/foxx-microservices/reference/related-modules/graphql/

And here

https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2017/03/24/arangodb-and-graphql/

Hope this helps!